# Choosing personalization slide in Jssor slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slide, jssor

First I have a slider with 3 images that rotate up and have a selector.

```
 var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);
```

I have a function in which, depending on the selected option in the select, I want to stop and show a specific slide the slider.

How could he?

This is the function that I have but does not work well.

```
$(".enlace").click(function(i){

    var id = $(this).attr("id");

    if(id == 'SDINERO'){

          options = {
            $AutoPlay: false,
            $StartIndex : 0,
            $PauseOnHover : 3
            };

         var jssor_slider2 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);

    }
    else{

        options = {
            $AutoPlay: false,
            $StartIndex : 1,
            $PauseOnHover : 3
            };

         var jssor_slider3 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);
     }  

    if(contador==0){

      var text = $(this).text();

      $('#tit').text(text);
      $("#proyecto").val(id);
      $("#proyecto").change();
      $(".enlace").slideUp('fast');
      $('#opaco').css('display','none');
      $('.main').css('display','block');
      $('#simulador-container').css('height','450px');
      $("#simulador-container").slideDown('fast');
      $('#slider1_container').css('height','495px');
      $("#slider1_container").slideDown('fast');

      contador = 1;
    }
    else{
      var id = $(this).attr("id");

      var text = $(this).text();

      $('#tit').text(text);
      $("#proyecto").val(id);
      $("#proyecto").change();
      $(".enlace").slideUp('fast'); 
    }
```

});

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want the slider switch to specified slide according to the option selected by user?

Comment: The functionality is the following. 

The main slide has 3 images and the selector has 8 options, I want you when you select the "SDINERO" option only shows the slide 1 and the slider stops. 
When you select the other options show slide number 3 and the slider stops. 

Will be shown only 3 slides rotating to enter the page

Answer (score 0):

You can do that job in following manner,

```
var options = {
    ...
    $AutoPlay: false,
    ...
};

var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);

function OptionSelectedHandler(optionValue)
{
    var slideIndex = 2;
    if(optionValue == "SDINERO"){
        slideIndex = 0;
    }
    jssor_slider1.$PlayTo(slideIndex);

    //optionally you can use following line to switch the slider to specified slide directly.
    //jssor_slider1.$GoTo(index);
}

//your code here to
//do something to capture the 'select' event and then call OptionSelectedHandler
```

Comment: I've made ​​the changes, capture the value of the "id" option select and call the function, enter the function (I've put a alert with the value of optionvalue) but when I enter a parameter like `jssor_slider1.$PlayTo(slideIndex);'. function stops. Does not recognize any value regarding the slider.

Comment: If the slider is already at slide 0, and then you call jssor_slider1.$PlayTo(0), it will do nonthing.